# AWS SDK GO V2 DynamoDB - ADD doesn't work anymore after migrating to V2

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I have this code which works with the Golang AWS SDK v1.
I tried to migrate to SDK v2 but it doesn't work anymore and I have this error:

> api error ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "Val"","time":"2021-04-09T15:05:09-04:00"

```
type counterValueInc struct {
    Val int `json:":inc"`
}

increment, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(counterValueInc{
        Val: 1,
    })

key, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(cKey)

if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Got error marshalling counter key")
    return err
}

input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        ExpressionAttributeValues: increment,
        TableName:                 aws.String(r.table),
        Key:                       key,
        UpdateExpression:          aws.String("ADD Ctr :inc"),
        ReturnValues:              types.ReturnValueNone,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "dynamodbav" key instead of "json" in your struct declaration. [see this doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue#hdr-Struct_tags)